# Conditional COPY/ADD in Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Inside of my Dockerfiles I would like to COPY a file into my image if it exists, the requirements.txt file for pip seems like a good candidate but how would this be achieved?

```
COPY (requirements.txt if test -e requirements.txt; fi) /destination
...
RUN  if test -e requirements.txt; then pip install -r requirements.txt; fi
```

or

```
if test -e requirements.txt; then
    COPY requiements.txt /destination;
fi
RUN  if test -e requirements.txt; then pip install -r requirements.txt; fi
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

2021+, from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70096420/6309), using [glob pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)), Docker COPY will not fail if it won't find any valid source

```
COPY requiements.tx[t] /destination
```

---

2015: This isn't currently supported (as I suspect it would lead to a non-reproducible image, since the same Dockerfile would copy or not the file, depending on its existence).

This is still requested, in [issue 13045](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/13045), using wildcards: "`COPY foo/* bar/" not work if no file in foo`" (May 2015).
It won't be implemented for now (July 2015) in Docker, but another build tool like **[bocker](https://github.com/icy/bocker)** could support this.

---

[2021](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/13045#issuecomment-990170325):

> `COPY source/. /source/` works for me (i.e. copies directory when empty or not, as in "[Copy directory into docker build no matter if empty or not - fails on "`COPY failed: no source files were specified`"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70295662/6309)")

[2022](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/13045#issuecomment-1180933136)

> Here is my suggestion:
>
> ```bash
> # syntax=docker/dockerfile:1.2
>
> RUN --mount=type=bind,source=jars,target=/build/jars \
>  find /build/jars -type f -name '*.jar' -maxdepth 1  -print0 \
>  | xargs -0 --no-run-if-empty --replace=source cp --force source >"${INSTALL_PATH}/modules/"
> ```
>
> That works around:
>
> ```
> COPY jars/*.jar "${INSTALL_PATH}/modules/"
> ```
>
> But copies no `*.jar` if none is found, without throwing an error.

Comment: good answer, but the docker logic, IMO, is flawed.
if you run the same dockerfile with a different build-context, you would get a different image. that's to be expected.
using the same build-context will give the same image. and if you insert conditional COPY/ADD instructions on the same build-context, you'll get the same image. so that checks out.
that's just my 2 cents though.

Comment: Docker is about immutable infrastructure. Your environments dev, staging and prod should be 99.99% as close as possible if not identical. Use environment variables.

Comment: @AndrewMcLagan what if, for instance, a front-end `dev` environment runs with a webpack dev server, and the equivalent `prod` environment works with a `/dist` static folder? This is the case in most front-end setups today, and obviously `dev` and `prod` cannot be the same here. So how to deal with that?

Comment: I don't use docker to develop my node front ends. The normal webpack localhost:3000 etc... Although still boot your local docker dev environment so your node/react/angular front end communicates to whatever is running in your normal docker container environment. E.g. APIs, redis, MySQL, mongo, elastic search and any other micro service. You ..could.., run a webpack dev environment in a container. But I feel it's too far...

Comment: @Jivan How about using an onbuild image to define the common instructions and then building specific images for dev and prod. The Docker Hub Node repo appears to contain onbuild images for each Node version: https://hub.docker.com/_/node/. Or maybe you could roll your own.

Answer (score 180):

Here is a simple workaround:

```
COPY foo file-which-may-exist* /target
```

Make sure `foo` exists, since `COPY` needs at least one valid source.

If `file-which-may-exist` is present, it will also be copied.

NOTE:
You should take care to ensure that your wildcard doesn't pick up other files which you don't intend to copy.  To be more careful, you could use `file-which-may-exist?` instead (`?` matches just a single character).

Or even better, use a character class like this to ensure that only one file can be matched:

```
COPY foo file-which-may-exis[t] /target
```

Comment: Can you do the same thing with a folder?

Comment: @BenjaminToueg: Yes, according to the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) you can copy files as well as folders.

Comment: This works great. For files with multiple destinations, I copied to a temporary directory and then moved them to where needed. `COPY --from=docker /usr/bin/docker /usr/lib/libltdl.so* /tmp/docker/` `RUN mv /tmp/docker/docker /usr/bin/docker` `RUN mv /tmp/docker/libltdl.so.7 /usr/lib/libltdl.so.7 || true` (where the shared library is the unknown entity.)

Comment: When copying multiple extant files the destination must be a directory. How does this work when both foo and your file-which-may-exist* exist?

Comment: So the answer is 'make sure there is a file' and then a demonstration on how to use the COPY operator? I fail to see how this relates to the original question.

Comment: @derrend: You can have logic which creates a file under certain conditions.  Then use the COPY command with a wildcard as described, so that if the file exists, it will be copied into the image.  This achieves what the OP is trying to do with `requirements.txt`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It is weird though that we need so weird workarounds...

Comment: To test whether the file was copied you can this in the Dockerfile
`RUN test -f /tmp/myfile.txt && echo "file exists"; exit 0`.
Exit 0 is needed afterwards otherwise the `test -f` command will exit with an error 
code if there's no file.

Answer (score 110):

As stated by [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31528384/conditional-copy-add-in-dockerfile#comment71079440_41256314), Santhosh Hirekerur's answer still copies the file, to achieve a true conditional copy, you can use this method.

```
ARG BUILD_ENV=copy

FROM alpine as build_copy
ONBUILD COPY file /file

FROM alpine as build_no_copy
ONBUILD RUN echo "I don't copy"

FROM build_${BUILD_ENV}
# other stuff
```

The `ONBUILD` instructions ensures that the file is only copied if the "branch" is selected by the `BUILD_ENV`. Set this var using a little script before calling `docker build`

Comment: I like this answer because it opened my eyes not only to ONBUILD, which is super handy, but it also seems the easiest to integrate with other variables passed in, e.g. if you want to set the tag based on BUILD_ENV, or store some state in ENV.

Comment: I just tried something like that and got:

Error response from daemon: Dockerfile parse error line 52: invalid name for build stage: "site_builder_${host_env}", name can't start with a number or contain symbols

Comment: @paulecoyote I am sure that you have since figured it out but in order to use an `ARG` in a `FROM` the `ARG` must be defined prior to the first `FROM`.  If you also want to use the same `ARG` within a `FROM`, like an `ENV`, then you must also define it inside of the scope of the `FROM`.  

[Understand how ARG and FROM interact](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-arg-and-from-interact)

Comment: So glad to find this answer! Solved my problem in a conditional multi-stage build!

Comment: I get: failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: failed to parse stage name "build_": invalid reference format

Comment: @404usernamenotfound the answer above from anthony-ledesma is the way to fix this issue, also.  Perhaps more recent versions of Docker manifest the error in a different way from paulecoyote's case, but the fix is the same.

Answer (score 44):

I think I came up with a valid workaround with this `Dockerfile`

```
FROM alpine
COPy always_exist_on_host.txt .
COPY *sometimes_exist_on_host.txt .
```

The `always_exist_on_host.txt` file will always be copied to the image and the build won't fail to COPY the `sometimes_exist_on_host.txt` file when it doesn't exist. Furthermore, it will COPY the `sometimes_exist_on_host.txt` file when it does exist.

For example:

```
.
├── Dockerfile
└── always_exist_on_host.txt
```

build succeeds

```sh
docker build . -t copy-when-exists --no-cache
[+] Building 1.0s (7/7) FINISHED                                                                                                                            
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 36B                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/alpine:latest                                                                                       1.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 43B                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => CACHED [1/2] FROM docker.io/library/alpine@sha256:c0e9560cda118f9ec63ddefb4a173a2b2a0347082d7dff7dc14272e7841a5b5a                                 0.0s
 => [2/2] COPY always_exist_on_host.txt *sometimes_exist_on_host.txt .                                                                                 0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:e7d02c6d977f43500dbc1c99d31e0a0100bb2a6e5301d8cd46a19390368f4899                                                           0.0s
```

---

```
.
├── Dockerfile
├── always_exist_on_host.txt
└── sometimes_exist_on_host.txt
```

build still succeeds

```sh
docker build . -t copy-when-exists --no-cache
[+] Building 1.0s (7/7) FINISHED                                                                                                                            
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                   0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 36B                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/alpine:latest                                                                                       0.9s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => transferring context: 91B                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => CACHED [1/2] FROM docker.io/library/alpine@sha256:c0e9560cda118f9ec63ddefb4a173a2b2a0347082d7dff7dc14272e7841a5b5a                                 0.0s
 => [2/2] COPY always_exist_on_host.txt *sometimes_exist_on_host.txt .                                                                                 0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                 0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:4c88e2ffa77ebf6869af3c7ca2a0cfb9461979461fc3ae133709080b5abee8ff                                                           0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/copy-when-exists                                                                                                    0.0s
```

Comment: I like it but wish there didn't need to be an 'always_exist_on_host.txt' file.

Comment: @derrend check my edit. I broke the COPY into two layers for the sake of the example.

Comment: 5 years - and finally solution is working :-)

Comment: I love this, but an explanation of how it works would be nice with the asterisk and without it.

Comment: @AidanMelen so do you say that one can choose to remove the first `COPY` and then we do not need the dummy file anymore?

Comment: @corwin.amber I included `COPY always_exist_on_host.txt .` to demonstrate how the COPY is typically used. The `COPY *sometimes_exist_on_host.txt .` is all you need.

Comment: Not working with the latest docker `Docker version 20.10.8, build 3967b7d`

Comment: @MarcellodeSales are you absolutely sure you're using the wildcard to conditionally copy a file at build time? It works for me with `Docker version 20.10.8, build 3967b7d`. no problems at all.

Comment: `COPY scripts/container/initdb/dev/*initdb-01.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/` does not work on `Docker version 19.03.14, build 5eb3275d40`. The directory also exists exists, only the file is absent. `COPY` command fails with : 


Step 11/20 : COPY scripts/container/initdb/dev/*initdb-01.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
COPY failed: no source files were specified
FAILED

Comment: A perfect solution!

We have a generic `Dockerfile` which uses parameters to decide what the base image is, and then copies in a `package.json` and runs `npm i`. However, some of the packages we are building also want to run a postinstall step. This solution lets us copy in the postinstall script when it's present, and do nothing otherwise.

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't appear to work when the optional file is in a subdirectory, i.e. `COPY subdir/*sometimes_exist_on_host.txt .`

Comment: it does, please double check the example

Answer (score 16):

Copy all files to a throwaway dir, hand pick the one you want, discard the rest.

```
COPY . /throwaway
RUN cp /throwaway/requirements.txt . || echo 'requirements.txt does not exist'
RUN rm -rf /throwaway
```

You can achieve something similar using build stages, which relies on the same solution, using `cp` to conditionally copy. By using a build stage, your final image will not include all the content from the initial `COPY`.

```
FROM alpine as copy_stage
COPY . .
RUN mkdir /dir_for_maybe_requirements_file
RUN cp requirements.txt /dir_for_maybe_requirements_file &>- || true

FROM alpine
# Must copy a file which exists, so copy a directory with maybe one file
COPY --from=copy_stage /dir_for_maybe_requirements_file /
RUN cp /dir_for_maybe_requirements_file/* . &>- || true
CMD sh
```

Comment: While this technically solves the problem, it does not decrease the size of the image. If you are trying to conditionally copy something huge (like a deep network model) you still inflate the size of the image, due to the way overlay fs works.

Comment: @DeusXMachina, what version of docker are you using? The docs contradict what you're saying https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#use-multi-stage-builds. The layers should not be preserved from a non-final build stage.

Comment: @cdosburn - I have observed this on 18.09. I was speaking mostly about the first example, staged builds should avoid that issue. And I think every FROM stage compactifies now, but you have me second guessing my recollection. I will have to experiment with some things.

Comment: @DeusXMachina, right only the second solution reduces image size.

Comment: that is nice workaround for my case. I copy a `cache` and depending whats it the cache I choose what to do in script files!

Answer (score 14):

### Work around Solution

I had requirement on copy FOLDER to server based on ENV Variables. I took the empty server image. created required deployment folder structure at in local folder. then added below line to **DockerFile** copy the folder to container. I**n last line added entry point to execute init file.sh before docker start the server.**

```
#below lines added to integrate testing framework
RUN mkdir /mnt/conf_folder
ADD install /mnt/conf_folder/install
ADD install_test /mnt/conf_folder/install_test
ADD custom-init.sh /usr/local/bin/custom-init.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/custom-init.sh"]
```

Then create the  **custom-init.sh** file in local with script something like below

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "${BUILD_EVN}" = "TEST" ]; then
    cp -avr /mnt/conf_folder/install_test/* /mnt/wso2das-3.1.0/
else
    cp -avr /mnt/conf_folder/install/* /mnt/wso2das-3.1.0/
fi;
```

In **docker-compose** file below lines.

environment:
      - BUILD_EVN=TEST

These changes copy folder to container during docker build. when we execute **docker-compose up**  it copy or deploy the actual required folder to server before server starts.

Comment: But docker images are layered. ADD would copy these to the image regardless of the if statement you mentioned...

Comment: @MyUserInStackOverflow - I think the idea of this "workaround" is that both install and install_test are copied into the image, but when the image is run, only one of those folders is copied to the final location. If its okay that both are somewhere in the image, this could be a reasonable technique.

Answer (score 2):

Tried the other ideas, but none met our requirement.  The idea is to create base nginx image for child static web applications.  For security, optimization, and standardization reasons, the base image must be able to `RUN` commands on directories added by child images.  The base image does not control which directories are added by child images.  Assumption is child images will `COPY` resources somewhere under `COMMON_DEST_ROOT`.

This approach is a hack, but the idea is base image will support `COPY` instruction for 1 to N directories added by child image.  `ARG PLACEHOLDER_FILE` and `ENV UNPROVIDED_DEST` are used to satisfy `<src>` and `<dest>` requirements for any `COPY` instruction not needed.

```
#
# base-image:01
#
FROM nginx:1.17.3-alpine
ENV UNPROVIDED_DEST=/unprovided
ENV COMMON_DEST_ROOT=/usr/share/nginx/html
ONBUILD ARG PLACEHOLDER_FILE
ONBUILD ARG SRC_1
ONBUILD ARG DEST_1
ONBUILD ARG SRC_2
ONBUILD ARG DEST_2
ONBUILD ENV SRC_1=${SRC_1:-PLACEHOLDER_FILE}
ONBUILD ENV DEST_1=${DEST_1:-${UNPROVIDED_DEST}}
ONBUILD ENV SRC_2=${SRC_2:-PLACEHOLDER_FILE}
ONBUILD ENV DEST_2=${DEST_2:-${UNPROVIDED_DEST}}

ONBUILD COPY ${SRC_1} ${DEST_1}
ONBUILD COPY ${SRC_2} ${DEST_2}

ONBUILD RUN sh -x \
    #
    # perform operations on COMMON_DEST_ROOT
    #
    && chown -R limited:limited ${COMMON_DEST_ROOT} \
    #
    # remove the unprovided dest
    #
    && rm -rf ${UNPROVIDED_DEST}

#
# child image
#
ARG PLACEHOLDER_FILE=dummy_placeholder.txt
ARG SRC_1=app/html
ARG DEST_1=/usr/share/nginx/html/myapp
FROM base-image:01
```

This solution has obvious shortcomings like the dummy `PLACEHOLDER_FILE` and hard-coded number of COPY instructions that are supported.  Also there is no way to get rid of the ENV variables that are used in the COPY instruction.

Answer (score 2):

COPY no longer requires at least one source to exist, and globbing doesn't fail if there are no matches, so you can just

```
COPY requirements.tx[t] /destination
```

This will copy `requirements.txt` if it exists, and won't fail if it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

It's simple with mount:

```bash
RUN --mount=target=/mnt \
    [ -f /mnt/requirements.txt ] && cp /mnt/requirements.txt . || :
```

More complex use case — looking for specific subdirectory:

```bash
RUN --mount=target=/mnt \
    if [ -d /mnt/toolchain/out ]; then \
      mkdir toolchain; \
      cp -r /mnt/toolchain/out toolchain; \
    fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I have other workarounds for the same. The idea is to touch the file in the build context and use the copy statement inside the Dockerfile. If the file exists it will just create an empty file and the docker build will not fail. If there is already a file it will just change the time stamp.

```
touch requirements.txt
```

and for Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9
COPY requirements.txt .
```