# Docker will first file of COPY be overwritten by second file of COPY when same filename

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want a conditional `COPY` in my `Dockerfile` but since this option does not exist I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31528384/conditional-copy-add-in-dockerfile) workaround. Assuming I have following case (filenames simplified):

```
COPY file1.txt another_folder/file1.txt* /etc/some_folder/
```

will the first `file1.txt` be overwritten by the second `another_folder/file1.txt` if the second exists? So that `/etc/some_folder/file1.txt` will be the one of `another_folder` if it exists, otherwise the first.

Both filenames will be the same name but not the same content.

To make it clear upfront, I want the described behaviour.

Comment: IMO it'd be better to move the conditionals to a build script outside the dockerfile

Comment: @stacksonstacks would you think it is a downside to do it like above? This seems very elegant if possible, but teach me if I'm wrong.

Comment: It see it as a code smell. This will create a single dockerfile which can produce two distinct images. Typically, 1:1 dockerfile to image is the way to go. Pressumably, the different config will be important in the final image and should be tagged as so

Comment: Checkout my answer on  the question, https://stackoverflow.com/a/54245466/4980651. It improves the workaround and it's easier to understand.

Comment: @Siyu thanks, but I'd like to have an answer to my question first as I'd like to understand if it works and why it would be not a good solution if it does work.

Answer (score 0):

Just run and see for yourself. Short answer: YES it does what you want

```
FROM alpine
COPY f1.txt t/f1.txt*  /
RUN cat f1.txt
```

In f1.txt, I put "aaa". In t/f1.txt, I put "bbb".

The build shows "bbb".

If I delete t/f1.txt, the build shows "aaa"

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Is there any reason not to use this?