# Dockerfile Copy command is not working with IF/Else

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am new to Docker. I am using the Copy command to copy some files and its working fine. But when I add those Copy Commands to IF/ElSE statement it stopped working and showing an error `returned a non-zero code: 127`. Please find below the code I am using.

```
RUN if [ "$FRONT_END_BUILD" = "false" ]; then \
      echo "front resources need not to copy" $FRONT_END_BUILD; \
  else \
    COPY --from=build /application/test.php /application/test.php;\
    COPY --from=build /application/reactPage.blade.php /application/reactPage.blade.php;\
    COPY --from=build /application/reactPageBlank.blade.php /application/reactPageBlank.blade.php;\
  fi
```

Comment: you can not user Dockerfile directive in sh

Comment: You can do like `ENTRYPOINT ["/application/run.sh"]` and move conditions into this file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional COPY/ADD in Dockerfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31528384/conditional-copy-add-in-dockerfile)

Comment: @DavidMaze I have already gone through that solution but its not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this (dummy Dockerfile):

```
FROM node:10.8-stretch as build

RUN mkdir -p /application/
WORKDIR /application
RUN touch .emptyfile
RUN ls -l

FROM alpine:3.4 

ENV TEMP = "false" 
ENV First = ""

RUN if [ "TEMP" = "false" ]; then \
      echo "front end is not required"; \
  else \
      echo "helo";\
  fi 


COPY --from=build /application/.emptyfile /application/resources/views/admin/master.blade.php* /bin/
```

The line to focus is

`COPY --from=build /application/.emptyfile /application/resources/views/admin/master.blade.php* /bin/`

What this line does is it'll copy the `/application/.emptyfile` which is just a dummy placeholder file, and keep this `/application/resources/views/admin/master.blade.php*` optional.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can do this.

```
COPY --from=build /application/test.php /application/test.php.backup
COPY --from=build /application/reactPage.blade.php /application/reactPage.blade.php.backup
COPY --from=build /application/reactPageBlank.blade.php /application/reactPageBlank.blade.php.backup

RUN if [ "$FRONT_END_BUILD" = "false" ]; then \
      echo "front resources need not to copy" $FRONT_END_BUILD; \
  else \
    mv /application/test.php.backup /application/test.php;\
    mv /application/reactPage.blade.php.backup /application/reactPage.blade.php;\
    mv /application/reactPageBlank.blade.php.backup /application/reactPageBlank.blade.php;\
  fi
```

Comment: Yes i can, But it will throw an exception at first line that "no such file or directory"