# Conditional COPY in Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, environment-variables, cloud, devops

I have an application with a production Dockerfile that copies our source code into the container, i.e:

`COPY . /app`

I would like to make this copy conditional, so that passing in a `CONTEXT=` environment variable prevents/allows this line to execute. Is that possible?

I saw [related posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54245466/447186) on here but no clear answer. Thanks!

Comment: ...how does the non-production Dockerfile get code into the image?  Why are the production and non-production images different?

Comment: The development container gets launched via Docker-Compose, which mounts a volume at `/app` and then (hopefully) loads this Dockerfile

Comment: @DavidMaze has a point, as the production and development container should be built the same. You could use a volume at `/app` without any problems, as it would override the image's content.

Comment: Thanks Gusavo, I did not know the volumes would override copied folders! Although that's not a perfect solution because the COPY command takes time to run, 20sec in my case...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [this post](https://blog.mikesir87.io/2018/07/leveraging-multi-stage-builds-single-dockerfile-dev-prod/) I discovered that Docker-Compose 3.7 supports targeting individual build stages.

So I created a Dockerfile with 2 stages, a `base` layer that sets up the container, then a  `deploy` that copies in the codebase:

```
# BUILD STAGE 1 - BASE
FROM webdevops/php-apache:7.2-alpine as base

# Do stuff

# BUILD STAGE 2 - DEPLOY
FROM base as deploy

# Add project
COPY . /app

# Do other stuff
```

Then I configured my dev `docker-compose.yml` to target only the base layer, and to mount a volume for the code.

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  app.base.img:
    build:
      context: .
      target: base
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
    container_name: app.base
```

My production pipeline builds the image normally (with both layers).

Note the version 3.7 declaration, apparently it's required.

This does what I want, thanks for all the comments and suggestions on this! If you think this is unwise feel free to comment.

Comment: Genius! I've been looking for a suitable solution, this is the best one I've seen so far!

Answer (score 3):

No. You should pre-process your project before building the final image.

Multistage builds might help you do that:

```
FROM debian AS builder
ARG CONTEXT
WORKDIR /final
COPY . /app
RUN bash -c "[ '$CONTEXT' = '1' ] || cp -rfv /app/* /final/"

FROM debian
COPY --from=builder /final /app
```

In this example, passing `--build-arg CONTEXT=1` prevents it from filling the `/app` folder in the final image, thus removing it from the final image.

Comment: Thanks for this example, this is a creative solution. I didn't know about the `COPY --from` feature! I'm going to keep the question open for now to see if anyone else has ideas