# Dockerfile: COPY folder if it exists (conditional COPY)

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have Dockerfile for NodeJS application and need to copy **migrations, seeds** folders inside container. But the problem is that all our applications use same Dockerfile, but not all of them work with DB and have **migrations, seeds**.

Dockerfile:

```
...
# * package json, to be able run `npm run ...`
COPY ./package.json /app/
# * migrations, seeds if they exist
COPY ./migrations/ /app/migrations/
COPY ./seeds/ /app/seeds/
...
```

Everything work ok, but if we don't have **migrations** folder we will get:

```
 => CACHED [app 4/9] COPY --from=builder /app/node_modules /app/node_modules                                                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => CACHED [app 5/9] COPY --from=builder /app/dist /app/dist                                                                                                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => CACHED [app 6/9] COPY ./package.json /app/                                                                                                                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => ERROR [app 7/9] COPY ./migrations/ /app/migrations/                                                                                                                                                                                                                   0.0s
------
 > [app 7/9] COPY ./migrations/ /app/migrations/:
------
failed to compute cache key: "/migrations" not found: not found
```

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional COPY/ADD in Dockerfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31528384/conditional-copy-add-in-dockerfile)

Comment: @HansKilian sort of, but it's about files not folders + `Make sure foo exists`, this will work even if `foo` doesn't exist

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**TL;DR;**

```
COPY ./migration[s]/ /app/migrations/
```

**More detailed answer**

We can use glob patterns to achieve such behavior, Docker will not fail if it won't find any valid source, there are 3-most used globs:

1. `?` - any character, doesn't match empty character
2. `*` - any characters sequence of any length, matches empty character
3. `[abc]` - sequence of characters to match, just like `?`, but it matches only characters defined in brackets

So there are 3 ways to solve this

1. `COPY ./migration?/ /app/migrations/` - will also match **migrationZ**, **migration2** and so on..
2. `COPY ./migrations*/ /app/migrations/` - will also match **migrations-cool**, **migrations-old**
3. `COPY ./migration[s]/ /app/migrations/` - will match *only* **migrations**, because we are using glob that is saying match any character from 1-item sequence `[s]` and it just can't anything except letter "s"

More about globs:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)

Comment: For some reason I get an error : 
Step 3/12 : COPY ./migration?/ /app/migrations/
COPY failed: no source files were specified

Docker version 20.10.7, build f0df350

Comment: And square brackets are working?

Comment: @EyalSolomon I see this failed message too when building in Jenkins. Locally, even though it doesn't copy, I still am amble to produce an image and use it.

Comment: Not working for me :
 => ERROR [ 6/16] COPY ./bdoc-portal/apps/_shell/dist*/ /bdoc-portal/apps/_shell/dist/                             0.0s
------
 > [ 6/16] COPY ./bdoc-portal/apps/_shell/dist*/ /bdoc-portal/apps/_shell/dist/:
------
lstat /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount3057941185/bdoc-portal/apps/_shell: no such file or directory

Comment: This worked for me on `Docker version 24.0.2, build cb74dfc` and `Docker Compose version v2.18.1`.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative solution I would advice you to create several docker images that inherit from a common base image. The base image is holding what is mutual and the child images having specifics requirements as in your case having the **migrations** and **seeds** folders.

Having conditionals in docker images is in my opinion not what an image is intended to do, as it is to create a common state shared between all clients.

Comment: Can't you provide some examples to solve his case?

Answer (score 2):

For whatever reason, when it hits this line as part of the final layer:

```
COPY --from=build ./src/image[s] ./images
```

It fails like so:

```
error building image: error building stage: failed to optimize instructions: failed to get files used from context: copy failed: no source files specified
```

The easy solution for my case was adding this to the build layer, so that it makes empty folders if they don't already exist.

```
RUN mkdir -p ./src/images
```

Works like a charm now, using the glob pattern or not (though the glob pattern isn't necessary for my case now so I took that bit out).