# Dockerfile conditional COPY of certs folder if exists

Tags: docker, ssl, amazon-ec2, amazon-linux-2

Running nodejs express app with letsencrypt certs for HTTPS.
CAN'T find a way to conditionally copy the generated certs folder it exists (exists on remote EC2 - not localy)

Docker version 20.10.7, build f0df350

Tried this 2 solution and can't make it to work

- [Dockerfile: COPY folder if it exists (conditional COPY)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70096208/dockerfile-copy-folder-if-it-exists-conditional-copy)
- [Conditional COPY/ADD in Dockerfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31528384/conditional-copy-add-in-dockerfile)

**First solution suggestions**

`docker build -t server .`

`COPY ./certs*/ ./certs/`

result

```
Step 3/15 : COPY ./certs*/ ./certs/
COPY failed: no source files were specified
```

**Second solution suggestions**

`docker build -t server .`

`COPY *sometimes_exist_on_host.txt .`

result

```
Step 3/15 : COPY *privkey.pem .
COPY failed: no source files were specified
```

Comment: You should probably use a `docker run -v` option or something similar to inject the certificates.  You really don't want to copy these certificates into your image as you're showing: anyone who gets a copy of the image can trivially extract them and impersonate your site.