# Check architecture in dockerfile to get amd/arm

Tags: docker, dockerfile, debian, x86-64, apple-m1

We're working with Windows and Mac M1 machines to develop locally using Docker and need to fetch and install a .deb package within our docker environment.

The package needs amd64/arm64 depending on the architecture being used.

Is there a way to determine this in the docker file i.e.

```
if xyz === 'arm64'
    RUN wget http://...../arm64.deb
else 
    RUN wget http://...../amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First you need to check if there is no other (easier) way to do it with the package manager.

You can use the `arch` command to get the architecture (equivalent to `uname -m`). The problem is that it does not return the values you expect (`aarch64` instead of `arm64` and `x86_64` instead of `amd64`). So you have to convert it, I have done it through a `sed`.

```
RUN arch=$(arch | sed s/aarch64/arm64/ | sed s/x86_64/amd64/) && \
    wget "http://...../${arch}.deb"
```

*Note: You should add the following code before running this command to prevent unexpected behavior in case of failure in the piping chain. See [Hadolint `DL4006`](https://github.com/hadolint/hadolint/wiki/DL4006) for more information.*

```
SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-o", "pipefail", "-c"]
```

Comment: This is great stuff. Works like a charm, I'll give it a whirl on Windows tomorrow but works perfectly on arm. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 3):

Later versions of Docker [expose info about the current architecture](https://www.docker.com/blog/faster-multi-platform-builds-dockerfile-cross-compilation-guide/) using global variables:

```
BUILDPLATFORM — matches the current machine. (e.g. linux/amd64)
BUILDOS — os component of BUILDPLATFORM, e.g. linux
BUILDARCH — e.g. amd64, arm64, riscv64
BUILDVARIANT — used to set ARM variant, e.g. v7
TARGETPLATFORM — The value set with --platform flag on build
TARGETOS - OS component from --platform, e.g. linux
TARGETARCH - Architecture from --platform, e.g. arm64
TARGETVARIANT
```

Note that you may need to `export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1` on headless machines for these to work, and they are enabled by default on Docker Desktop.

Use in conditional scripts like so:

```
RUN wget "http://...../${TARGETARCH}.deb"
```

You can even [branch Dockerfiles by using ONBUILD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54245466) like this:

```
FROM alpine as build_amd
# Intel stuff goes here
ONBUILD RUN apt-get install -y intel_software.deb

FROM alpine as build_arm
# ARM stuff goes here
ONBUILD RUN apt-get install -y arm_software.deb

# choose the build to use for the rest of the image
FROM build_${TARGETARCH}
# rest of the dockerfile follows
```