# Is it possible to conditionally copy at docker build if an argument is not empty?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

First, I already searched about conditional copy at docker build, and either that does not apply to my problem or this is just a workaround, and note for now I use [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46801962/11159476) like this:

```
ARG FILE_ARG="FAKE_NAME_TO_NOT_COPY_ANYTHING_I_DONT_WANT"
COPY ${FILE_ARG}* /
COPY ScriptThatManagesFileIfExists.sh /
RUN /ScriptThatManagesFileIfExists.sh "${FILE_ARG}"
```

But I want to go further, indeed, with this method if I may want to copy a file that I think is present but is not, then, with this for instance:

```
docker build --build-arg FILE_ARG=path/to/FileIThinkExistsButNot -t my-image .
```

I'll get no error and may miss the fact that file is missing and has not been managed until I use built image or later.

Ideally I want to do something like:

```
ARG FILE_ARG=""
IF ${FILE_ARG} not empty
    COPY "${FILE_ARG}" /
    RUN Whatever I want to do with "${FILE_ARG}" and fails if does not exist
```

Anyone knows if this is possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found another workaround that does the job:

```
ARG FAKE_NAME="FAKE_NAME_TO_NOT_COPY_ANYTHING_WE_DONT_WANT"
ARG FILE_ARG="${FAKE_NAME}"
COPY ${FILE_ARG}* /
RUN [[ "${FILE_ARG}" != "${FAKE_NAME}" ]] && Whatever I want to do with "${FILE_ARG}" that fails if does not exist || true
```

On `docker build --build-arg FILE_ARG=path/to/FileIThinkExistsButNot -t my-image .` call `"${FILE_ARG}" != "${FAKE_NAME}"` will be `true` and `Whatever I want to do with "${FILE_ARG}" that fails if does not exist` will be executed and fail if file has not actually been copied.

But still, this is a workaround and I prefer having a proper method that simply fails on `COPY` if file does not exist.