# Conditional COPY/ADD in Podman file?

Tags: dockerfile, podman

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31528384/conditional-copy-add-in-dockerfile) for Docker.

Inside of my Dockerfile/Podmanfile I would like to COPY a file into my image if it exists, the requirements.txt file for pip seems like a good candidate but how would this be achieved?

The suggested solution for Docker does not work for Podman. Is there are solution when using Podman?

Answer (score 0):

I've not got access to a PC to test this out but supposedly this is now supported like it is in Docker in podman 3.2 which is available in Debian 12.

https://github.com/containers/buildah/issues/3284